# How do I stop the creation of a Laravel model where two fields are equal?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table called `purchase_records`. One field in the purchase records table is called `buyer`, and another is called `seller` - these fields both relate back to the `users` table, and they cannot have the same value.

MySQL doesn't support check constraints, if this were another SQL server, I could add this to the bottom of the migration that creates the table:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE purchase_records ADD CONSTRAINT different_users CHECK (seller <> buyer)");
```

I don't think that there is a way for Laravel to easily listen to MySQL triggers, so my proposed solution is to override the `create()` method on the `PurchaseRecord` model - as follows:

```
public static function create(array $attributes = [])
{
    if ($attributes['buyer'] === $attributes['seller'] {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException();
    }

    return static::query()->create($attributes);
}
```

I am using the repository pattern for purchase records, and there are policies and validation governing who can do what, but I want to ensure that at the lowest levels of my app, a user can't purchase something from themselves - is this the best way to ensure that?

Comment: That's a possibility. Another option would be to validate the input directly. Just check if the seller_id is different from Auth::id() - > otherwise send the user back to the view with a validation error..

Comment: You can also use model events, `creating` should be good, just return false to skip creation.

Comment: @jtwes It’s a REST API in this instance, so there’s no view to kick back to the user. Also, we’re checking that the auth_id !== seller_id - this is done automatically when a transaction is completed, and doesn’t necessitate a user visiting a route, so I was thinking that the best option at that level is a policy rule that says that the two can’t match - but I think it would return a 403 response on error.

Comment: @dparoli If I return false, will that throw an error message back to whatever called the create() method? Ideally I’d like to return feedback. Also, I’d have do the same on update() and save, wouldn’t I?

Comment: Read here, model events: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events. Use the creating event, in the observer if you return false the creation is skipped. The same for the updating event. Hope this helps.